# I am unable to successfully import pywinauto into python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x, exception, import, pywinauto

I began with a pip install of "pywinauto" and attempted to import it, and I initially I got a message saying that the module `win32api` was missing.  I attempted a pip install of that module but received a message saying that no satisfactory version could be found.

I then downloaded a copy of it from the web which when I tried to install it informed me that I don't have Python 3.6 installed on my system(!)
I had a number of installations of earlier versions and worried that they might be causing a problem so I deleted them and tried again, no success.  The path to my executable is `C:\Python36\python.exe`.

I went to the `site-packages` folder and deleted the `pywinauto` and `pywinauto-0.6.4-py3.6.egg-info` folders and did a fresh pip install which concluded with the message: "Successfully installed pywinauto-0.6.4" and attempted to import it again.

This time I got the following:

```
import pywinauto

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
from . import findwindows
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <module>
from . import controls
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
from . import uiawrapper # register "uia" back-end (at the end of uiawrapper module)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 46, in <module>
from ..uia_defines import IUIA
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 181, in <module>
pattern_ids = _build_pattern_ids_dic()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 169, in _build_pattern_ids_dic
if hasattr(IUIA().ui_automation_client, cls_name):
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 50, in __call__
cls._instances[cls] = super(_Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 63, in __init__
self.ui_automation_client.CUIAutomation().IPersist_GetClassID(),
AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient' has no attribute 'CUIAutomation'
```

At this point I really don't know what to do.  It appears that one of the imported files is lacking something that another one needs.  I would be grateful for any ideas......

Answer (score 0):

The correct dependency can be installed so:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Previously it was `pypiwin32` but something is changed in these packages maintenance and `pywin32` became official again. pywinauto 0.6.5 will reflect these changes soon.

The second issue looks like known comtypes issue with generating cache files for UI Automation type library. The workaround assumes running the script as Administrator at least first time to have an access to comtypes cache folder. Unfortunately comtypes maintainers are not so active and there are a number of pull requests with very similar fixes and they all still hang unaccepted.

Comment: Vasily, I tried "pip install pywin32" and got "Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages <223>".  I'm hoping you might be able to clarify what you meant in the second paragraph.  It appears that you're suggesting that I get an administrator to try to import the module the first time?  Should I ask him/her to do something in particular?  Please understand that I am fairly new to this and am a bit confused.

Comment: OK, you already have pyWin32 installed and it's not a problem any more. For the `comtypes` issue you should right click on `cmd.exe` and choose context menu option "run as Administrator" and then press Yes on confirmation dialog. When `cmd.exe` is started, run `python <path_to_your_script.py>`.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov facing the exact same issue. running the script as administrator didn't help.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov do you mean the `C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen` directory? Did that, but it keeps throwing the `ImportError: Typelib newer than module` error.

Comment: @Madhur need to downgrade comtypes by `pip install comtypes==1.1.2` before removing cache dir. I've just fixed it in comtypes, hope `comtypes==1.1.5` will be out this weekend.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov there's no comtypes `1.1.2` on **pip**, tried installing `1.1.3.post2` and that gives a `TypeError: '_NamespacePath' object does not support indexing`

Comment: Well, it's simpler to wait for comtypes update release. The fix is here: https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/pull/153